# Angular/Typescript function(){} vs ()=>{}

Tags: angular, typescript, this

**Angular/Typescript:** Could someone please give an **easily understandable explanation** of the difference between `function(){}` and `()=>{}`

I know it affects the **this** keyword but I am not exactly sure how. Please don't reference me to docs as docs aren't always easily understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function(){}` uses its own context, aka `this` refers to the function's context.

`()=>{}` (also named arrow functions) keep the context of the object where they are declared, which is why it's used a lot in callbacks, to avoid `const that = this`.